# How to create RSA keys smaller than 384 bits in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

For testing purposes and developing a Proof of Concept in C#, I need to generate RSA keys smaller than the minimum alowwed by LegalKeySizes, 384 bits. I've been reviewing all the documentation about RSACryptoServiceProvider, RSA, AssymetricAlgorithm and other classes, but didn't find a straightforward method to change the minimum value in LegalKeySizes. Any idea?

I know all the regulatory staff, these are certificates intended for testing purposes, not for deployment. Please, don't tell me that it has no sense to produce 128-bit RSA certificates. It's for a PoC!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Don't .. just don't use a short key..

Comment: The minimum size isn't a recommendation, it's a hard limit *for this implementation*. Simply put, you cannot construct a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instance with a shorter key than 384 bits. If you need to do this, you need to find an alternate implementation.

Comment: What benefit would you expect this to provide?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum key length of RSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674105/minimum-key-length-of-rsa)

Comment: @kelalaka That question revolves around something else, whether 384 is the minimum for the algorithm, to which the answer is no, but the .NET implementation has imposed 384 as a hard lower limit, so those are different questions.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen There is a comment says `You can't use typical paddings with such short keys. For example OAEP with SHA1 takes 328 bits by itself. `

Comment: If it's a testing purpose the bits size is not important. It's doesn't make it slower to the point of not working at all. And yes it would make no sense to do 128bit as it has no effect on the end result of a PoC. Making it 512 bits or 1024 bits has not bearing on test. You can change whenever you want.

Comment: As indicated, many tests would fail *because* of the smaller key size, so this is not a good idea. If your key generation takes too much CPU time then you should probably review *when* you are generating your keys within your testing framework. Maybe tests could share a particular key pair, or they could even be using a static key (you would want to share your ideas with your colleagues on this, because this is dangerous territory, of course).

Comment: I only need the values of p, q, and n. I'm using millions of n values. To develop the PoC I need speed. That's why the size IS VERY IMPORTANT. If my PoC works for a 128-bit keylength, it will work for any length. But to prove this, first I need millions of n values of short length, such as 128 bits. I thought of using RSACryptoServiceProvider class because is extremely fast generating p, q, and n, but then I hit with this limit. If you know of some other fast method to generate p, q, and n, it will serve me equally well. Thanks a lot for your comments.